# How can a bijection be made from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ using diagonalization?

Tags: infinity

I'm studying Cantor's diagonalization, but something seems unclear to me.

There is this table for diagonalization:

```
╔═══════════════════════╗
║ X  1   2   3   4   5  ║
║ 1 1/1 1/2 1/3 1/4 1/5 ║
║ 2 2/1 2/2 2/3 2/4 2/5 ║
║ 3 3/1 3/2 3/3 3/4 3/5 ║
║ 4 4/1 4/2 4/3 4/4 4/5 ║
║ 5 5/1 5/2 5/3 5/4 5/5 ║
╚═══════════════════════╝
```

And there can be a bijection between the diagonal

From 2/1 -> 1/2

From 3/1 -> 1/3 (diagonals)

From 4/1 -> 1/4

I don't understand where the bijection really is? I guess 2/1=2 ($\mathbb{N}$) is mapped to 1/2 ($\mathbb{Q}$)

But what about 2/5? I can only see that 2/5 will make |$\mathbb{N}$| < |$\mathbb{Q}$|

However, I can only think that |$\mathbb{N}$x$\mathbb{N}$| = |$\mathbb{Q}$|

What am I missing or misunderstanding and where's the bijection? Can you give me 2 elements that are mapping to each other?

Comment: follow the arrows: https://qph.is.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-7f948c04fbc3859f685fe3c57aa5347a?convert_to_webp=true

Comment: It can't be $\left\vert \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \right\vert = \left\vert \mathbb Q \right\vert$, as, for example, $\frac{1}{2}=\frac{2}{4}=\frac{3}{6}=\cdots$ is repeated. This happens with every element and its equivalence class.

Comment: just thought of that, but still I can't see how it would be equal in size, if you think about 2/5, 3/5, those can't be reduced and there is no smaller way in order to represent this, so the $\mathbb{N}$ value 5 should map to more than 1 number?
@ThePortakal I still don't understand, which value of $\mathbb{N}$ maps to which value of $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Look at the picture in the link: $1 \mapsto \frac 11$, $2 \mapsto \frac 21$, $3 \mapsto \frac 12$, $4 \mapsto \frac 13$, $5 \mapsto \frac 31$ ($5 \mapsto \frac 22$ is not true because we alrealy counted $\frac 11$), $6 \mapsto \frac 41$, $7 \mapsto \frac 32$ etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this sequence and see if it helps:

1 maps to 1/1

2 maps to 2/1

3 maps to 1/2

4 maps to 1/3

5 maps to 3/1 (As the 2/2 is already included in the list we are building)

6 maps to 4/1

7 maps to 3/2

8 maps to 2/3

9 maps to 1/4

10 maps to 1/5

11 maps to 5/1 (As the others are already done on this diagonal.)

12 maps to 6/1

13 maps to 5/2

14 maps to 4/3

15 maps to 3/4

16 maps to 2/5

Thus there is keeping track of what is already handled if there are common factors.

Comment: If 1 and 5 both get mapped to the same number,  I don't see how this is a bijection.

Comment: That helps! Didn't know that's how I was supposed to read the arrows :). I think I got the concept of "same size" of infinity is wrong. As I see it, even if you remove doubles: `1 would map to 1/1`. `2 would map to { 1/2, 2/1 }`. `3 would map to { 1/3, 2/3 }`. And as I see here, the set of $\mathbb{N}$ would be smaller than  $\mathbb{Q}$. I guess my reasoning is wrong?

Comment: Fine, I'll tweak it so there isn't the over counting being done.

Comment: The idea is to show how this mapping can take any rational and map it to a natural and vice versa. Thus, the cardinality of the sets are the same whether it be naturals, integers or rationals even.

Comment: Alright, I guess I'm thinking too much on this one! It's pretty clear, just get any kind of bijection between the two sets and they have the same cardinality. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This answer may not be what you're looking for, but the fact is that in this proof, one rarely actually gives a bijection itself. Instead, the countability of the rationals is proved much more easily using some simpler theorems.

Namely, a countable union of countable sets is countable.

Now define $A_n$ as the set of rationals in reduced form with denominator $n$. For example, $A_1$ is the set of integers, $A_2$ is the set of odd numbers with denominator $2$, and so forth.

Since each of these sets is countable, we have $\Bbb{Q}=A_1\cup A_2\cup A_2\cup\cdots$ is rational.

Now to relate that back to diagonalization, it turns out that Cantor is basically doing the same thing. To be rigorous, once we count a number, we have to remove it from the list. So once we could $1/1$, we need to remove $2/2$, $3/3$, etc.

One possible bijection could start as follows: $1/1$ maps to $1$, $2/1$ maps to $2$, $1/2$ maps to $3$, and so on. The point that I am trying to make is that the bijection itself doesn't really matter; the point is that we know we can make one.

Comment: There is no need to invoke countable unions of countable sets are countable (whose proof uses the axiom of choice) here.